# Hello, how to get a string between commas

Tags: powershell, replace, split, powershell-2.0, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the  number in the middle of a sentences with some comma.

I have a powershell.ps1 file that contain array bellow

```
$Person = "Tom,Jerry,Buldog,12345,Cartoon"
```

I'm trying to get the 12345 only.

This is the code I tried

```
(Get-Content c:\powershel.ps1 | Select-Object -First 1) -replace”.*= " -replace '"' -replace '.*,'
```

But the result I got is just `Cartoon`.

Comment: Is the data you want always in the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using by split function. The first element starts with '0'.

```
$Person = "Tom,Jerry,Buldog,12345,Cartoon"
$array = $Person.Split(",")
$array[3]
```